# Configuring jasmine-jquery to work with Karma

Tags: gruntjs, jasmine, karma-runner, jasmine-jquery

I am trying to configure Karma to use jasmine-jquery without success ...

In my **karma.conf.js** file I have configured the framework:

```
frameworks: ['jasmine'],
```

and have loaded the required dependencies:

```
    files: [
        '../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
        '../bower_components/jasmine-jquery/lib/jasmine-jquery.js',
        ...
```

But when I run my test using **grunt test**, I have the following:

```
    TypeError: undefined is not a function
        at null.<anonymous> (/home/sofarell/workspace/myapp/bower_components/jasmine-jquery/lib/jasmine-jquery.js:352:13)
```

Looking at the source code of **jasmine-jquery.js**, it looks like it's not finding the jasmine reference probably because jasmine-jquery is being loaded before jasmine:

```
351. beforeEach(function () {
352.   jasmine.addMatchers({
353.     toHaveClass: function () {
```

Anyone else has faced this problem?
Is there a way to solve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just worked through this myself, turns out my karma-jasmine version was too old (`~0.1.5`).  Bumped it to `~0.2.0` in packages.json, did an `npm install`, which installed `0.2.2`, and it worked.  This [github issue from the jasmine-jquery repo](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery/issues/168) was the key.

Comment: Hi Tarek, thanks very much for the answer! It finally worked!